# Can't install python-setuptools with yum on Ubuntu. Missing repolist

Tags: ubuntu, python, yum, setuptools

I can't install on Ubuntu using the following command

```
sudo yum install python-setuptools
```

I get this message

```
Setting up Install Process
No package python-setuptool available.
```

So I checked my repolist

```
sudo yum repolist
```

that return

```
repolist: 0
```

Wich repository should I add, Or what else could I be missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using `yum` on ubuntu and not `apt` or `aptitude` ?

Comment: just because all the resources I have found used it

Comment: @svassr We have an [Ubuntu Specific Stack Exchange Site](http://askubuntu.com/) which may be a better fit for questions like this which are not specifically about server administration (we generally don't mind answering these kinds of questions here either, but I like to point people their way because they have a lot of deep Ubuntu-specific knowledge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu generally doesn't use yum, unless yo've taken specific steps to enable it.

Instead, use apt:

`apt-get install python-setuptools`

I highly recommend reading through the Ubuntu package management pages: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/package-management.html (they'll probably say to use some newer version of the apt command, which I'm guessing someone here on SF will educate me about in a comment or another answer).

Comment: Thanks Jed. What about adding repolist to yum. I'm still interested in learning how to do so.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. If I wanted to use yum, I's use a RedHat based system like CentOS instead of a Debian based system like Ubuntu. My understanding is that yum in based on aptitude anyway. If you really want to learn about it, I'm sure `man yum` will get you started.